# angular2 - template not appearing

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm having a problem where the template in my app.component.ts and superheroes.ts won't load. (I'm doing a test project similar to the Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial, but with a Django backend.) The title (ie. "You are in the Hall of Heroes") will display, so clearly my app.components.ts file is being read, but the "Welcome!" is not loading, and neither is the list of superheroes. (**edit**: I also do not get any errors in the console when I run. Everything seems to be compiling correctly.)

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroComponent } from './components/hero/superheroes'
import { HeroService } from './services/heroService'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div>
           <h1>Welcome!</h1>
           <superheroes></superheroes>
         </div>`,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "You are in the Hall of Heroes";
}
```

*superheroes.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroService } from '../../services/heroService'

@Component({
  selector: 'superheroes',
  template: `
    <ul><li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}}</li></ul>
  `
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: any[];
  error: any;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes() {
    this.heroService
      .getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes)
      .catch(error => this.error = error);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }
}
```

*heroService.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  private apiURL = 'http://localhost:8000/superheroes/?format=json';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getHeroes() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { HeroComponent } from './components/hero/superheroes';
import { HeroService } from './services/heroService';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm really scratching my head over this, but I can't shake the feeling that I'm missing something super obvious. If you need me to add any extra code/explain what I have, just say so and I'll edit my post, but I think this is good.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, there aren't any. When I run npm start, it says everything compiles successfully. And like I said above, I am having some text display when I view the project in the browser, just not all the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you defined `template` and `templateUrl` on your `AppComponent`. So angular is choosing the HTML file set as `templateUrl` as the components template.

Either set `template` or `templateUrl`, i would recommend to use `templateUrl`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "You are in the Hall of Heroes";
}
```

And move the template string into `app.component.html`:

```
<div>
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>
  <superheroes></superheroes>
</div>
```